# Responsive CSS - Multiple Files Only One Working

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm working on making my current design responsive. I started out using `@media screen...` but nothing in the design would change. I attempted using the `html, div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }` to see if that would at least help the fonts change sizes (I'm using em), but nothing changed.

Then I switched to `<link type="text/css"...`. I currently have 3 media query files linked in my HTML document and I'm using HTML5/CSS3.

My question is: Why is the document only referencing the first file? I took out the core stylesheet and am using nothing but directly targeted sheets to see if that would stop it from just using the first stylesheet, but it hasn't.  The fonts haven't resized. The containers won't resize. The images won't resize or remove. Only the first stylesheet is referenced - the others are ignored.

These are my current linked stylesheets:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 1280px)" href="scripts/css/style.css" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 800px)" href="scripts/css/style800.css" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="scripts/css/style1024.css" />
```

Edit: The stylesheet does change from one to the other, but the styles themselves don't change. It's like 1280 stylesheet is overridding all the others with its styles.

Comment: Are you just adjusting your browser window? Your media queries are looking for device width. You could try changing them to just min-width and max-width.

Comment: I'm currently running it through Screenfly to see it on mobile devices and different desktop sizes. The only one it's referencing is that 1280 stylesheet.

Edit: Grillz, I just tried your suggestion. Still only references that first stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for max-width instead of max-device-width?

Former is for display area like the browser for example and the latter is the actual device area.

Also, you want to put the smallest one (800px in your case) at the end.

try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 1280px)" href="scripts/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 1024px)" href="scripts/css/style1024.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 800px)" href="scripts/css/style800.css" />
```

Comment: Definitely want to use min-width/max-width as those are the only ones supported by respond.js at the time of this writing.

Comment: So, what about when it's viewed on a mobile device. Will the min-width still apply there?

Comment: Excellent. Thank all of you so much.

Answer (score 1):

How do you debug them?
Try resizing the browser, these should work. 
Also, I really dont suggest to use 800px, as iPad will also fall in it, you are better of using 767.

Comment: I use Firebug to debug. I know the iPad will break at 800px. This is just testing right now. I had it set at 768, but then I changed it to 800 to do a separate test for size change.

Speaking of debugging. It does seem to switch to the style800.css, but none of the styles change. I better clarify this in the post.

Comment: You can just open it in chrome/firefox and resize your web browser. Like cssgrid.net

Comment: And you will have to set it to 767 and 768.